# firebase set not accepting nested dictionary

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

Firebase set function not working for nested dictionaries

```
const [appInitialized, setAppInitialized] = useState(false)

// Where FireBase is name of function that initializes firebase

FireBase().then(() => {
    setAppInitialized(true)
})

const [user, loading, error] = useAuthState(firebase.auth());


useEffect(() => {
    if (appInitialized) {
        SingingInAnonymously()
    }
}, [appInitialized, loading])


function SingingInAnonymously() {
    if (!loading) {
        if (!user && !loading) {
            firebase.auth().signInAnonymously()
                .then((response) => {


                    const reference = "Users/" + response.user.uid
                    console.log("RUNNING TO ADD USER", reference)
                    firebase.database().ref(reference).set(
                        {
                            CurrentAvatar: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/just-an-app-96ed6.appspot.com/o/Avatars%2FRad.png?alt=media&token=dae7e13b-ac3a-4fd9-a5e5-8342e84dc13e",
                            UnlockedAvatars: ["PushID1"]
                        }
                    ).then((e) => console.log("success")).catch((e)=>console.log(e))
                    setAppInitialized(false)
                }).catch((e) => {
            })
        }
    }

}
```

I have also tried with

```
 UnlockedAvatars: { "0" : "PushID1" }
```

if i change "set" to "push" it works, otherwise it doesn't work, doesn't give any error nor it goes to then statement.

also if i remove the nested dictionary **UnlockedAvatars: ["PushID1"]** / **UnlockedAvatars: {"0": "PushID1"}** it works

If i change reference to a constant string, it still works

Answer (score 0):

I have tried it out and it actually works. I created a simple react app which was able to update the database successfully.

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import firebase from "firebase/app";
import 'firebase/database'
const firebaseConfig = {
  // ...
}

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
var database = firebase.database()
const App = () => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    let reference = 'cities'
    database.ref(reference).set(
      {
          CurrentAvatar: "wer",
          UnlockedAvatars: {"0": "PushID1"},
          extraAvatars: ["PushID1"]
      }
  ).then(() => console.log("success")).catch((e)=>console.log(e))
  }, [])
  return (
    <div>App</div>
  )
}


let container = document.getElementById('app');

ReactDOM.render(<App />, container)
```

[![Image showing database output][1]][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Unyo2.png

Comment: This is weird, it works normally but inside my use case it doesn't work

Comment: kindly check again i have edited the post with my full code